Regex pattern sanitization for wildcard replacement
I need a function to sanitize regex patterns in Python, specifically targeting strings that may contain wildcard characters (%). The goal is to replace these % wildcards with the regex equivalent .* to allow for flexible matching in regex patterns. Additionally, the function should ensure that special regex characters are escaped appropriately without adding unnecessary escape characters.
Requirements:

Convert % to .* in the provided regex patterns.
Escape special regex characters only when necessary, avoiding unnecessary escape sequences.
Maintain the integrity of existing regex patterns.

Examples:

Input: %core account.*?Annual Percentage Yield%
exp Output: .*?core account.*?Annual Percentage Yield.*?
String: Your core account offers an Annual Percentage Yield of 3.25%. This account is ideal for saving.

Input: interest rate on your account ((\d+\.\d+)|[^.])*?([\d+.]+%)
Output: interest rate on your account ((\d+\.\d+)|[^.])*?([\d+.]+.*?)
String: The interest rate on your account is 1.75%, while promotional rates are as high as 2.00%.


few more inputs:
1: Overdraft Protection Service Fee[^.]*?(\\$\\d+)

2: APY was accurate as of ([^\\s]+)

3: Cuenta de Ahorro opcional 6Obtenga hasta un ([^\\s]*) de porcentaje de rendimiento anual

4: \\bVisa\\b

5: withdrawals(.*?) per day

6: ([^a-zA-Z\\s]+) total is calculated based on all withdrawals

7: activate .*? calling ([^\\s]+)

I tried the following approach:
def _sanitize_regex(rhs: string):
    # Replace '%' wildcards with '.*?' for regex matching
    rhs = rhs.replace('%', '.*?')

    # Define special characters that need to be escaped in regex
    special_chars = ['$', '^', '[', ']', '{', '}', '|', '+', '<', '>', '\\']
    
    sanitized_rhs = []
    inside_group = False  # Track whether we're inside a group (e.g., parentheses or brackets)

    for char in rhs:
        # Handle opening and closing of groups
        if char in ['(', '[', '{']:
            inside_group = True
            sanitized_rhs.append(char)
        elif char in [')', ']', '}']:
            inside_group = False
            sanitized_rhs.append(char)
        # Escape special characters only if they are not inside a group
        elif char in special_chars:
            if not inside_group:  # Only escape if we are not inside a group
                sanitized_rhs.append(f"\\{char}")
            else:
                sanitized_rhs.append(char)  # Do not escape inside groups
        else:
            sanitized_rhs.append(char)

    # Join sanitized parts back together
    return ''.join(sanitized_rhs)

But it did not work for the following inputs:


interest rate on your account ((\d+.\d+)|[^.])*?([\d+.]+%)


output: interest rate on your account ((\d+\.\d+)\|[^.])*?([\d+.]\+.*?)
extra \ was being added by the above code. Can you help me sanitize the strings to get valid regex, considering the above requirements?

"Escape special regex characters only when necessary" -- how do you know when they're necessary?

Python-re already has a built-in function to escape special characters: re.escape()

In your examples you haven't escaped any special characters. Why not?

"Escape special regex characters only when necessary" > In regex, certain characters have special meanings, for ex: . (matches any character), If you want to match a literal dot in a string, you would use \. in your regex pattern. If you didn't escape it, it would match any character. "Avoiding Unnecessary Escapes:" > In the pattern hello.world, the dot is used as a literal character because it is not treated as a special character when surrounded by letters. Thus, hello.world would be unnecessary unless you specifically want to treat the dot as a special character.

And what if you want to match hello and world with any character between them, so you inteded . as the special regexp character?

Why does your code disable replacing special characters inside () and {}? What if you have (hello.world.*)? .* should be left alone, but . should be escaped.

And special-casing {} seems all wrong. The only special meaning of {} is for quantifiers like foo{1,5}. There should never be text inside the {}.

If I want to match "hello" and "world" with any characters in between, I would use hello.*?world, and If I want to match the specific text "hello.world", I would escape the dot with hello\.world. Basically the context in which the character in the input appears in the pattern determines this decision. And the input is already a partial regex containing %, I want to replace it with valid regex, without modifying the rest of the valid characters.

.*? is the same as .*.

No, that is a typo from my end. I wanted to replace % with .*. Thank you for pointing out, I will update the question description.

hello.world matches hello and world with any single character between them e.g. hello,world and hello:world. hello.*world allows any number (including zero) of characters between the words, e.g. hello there world`. It just seems like trying to guess which special characters were meant literally from heuristics like this will be error-prone.
